# stop the volume of a media element decreasing when a windows 8 app is sent to the background

Tags: c#, windows-8, volume, mediaelement

I have an app which uses a media element to play some background music and I want to stop it lowering the volume of the music when the app is sent to the background.

Is there a way to stop this and if so how?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can lower the volume in application's `Suspending` event or that pages's [`VisibilityChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.visibilitychanged%28v=win.10%29.aspx) event.